# Use openbox instead of kwin in Plasma 5

Tags: openbox, plasma

In old versions of KDE it was possible to configure DE to use different compozitors than kwin in the what is now called system settings (kcontrolcenter). How to achieve this in Plasma 5? I don't want to run `openbox --replace` each time I log in.

Comment: I currently use autostart scripts, but there should be a setting to prevent kwin from loading altogether)